TCPDF cannot apply Italic-Bold Calibri font style
You should know
I converted the calibriz.ttf using php tools\tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueType -i calibriz.ttf and stored under the application\libraries\fonts. FYI I also did install all the calibri tff(s) just that italic-bold doesn't work properly.

Issue
I tried to implement this, but TCPDF did not recognise. However, others like "bold", "italic" works if i use them separately:
$html = "<p style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><b><i>Test Italic Bold</i></b><p>"
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, 'C');

Result


Solution
The solution is renaming the calibriz.ttf to calibribi.ttf (changing "z" to "bi") and covert it using php tools\tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueType -i calibribi.ttf. Boom, done. Problem solved. Cheers. What an odd TCPDF :)
